# C#: Passing DataTable to SQL Server very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I have C# code that takes a DataTable returned from a SELECT on database A and passes it as a table-valued parameter to a stored procedure on database B via Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteDataSet method. There are about 200K rows in the table. In our test environment, where A and B are on the same server, it just takes a few seconds to execute the stored procedure. But in production, the ExecuteDataSet call is taking almost 30 minutes. Examination of the database logs shows that almost all that time is consumed between the start of the ExecuteDataSet call and the start of the stored procedure.

In test, both databases are on a single server. In production A and B are located on different servers.

What could be causing this extreme delay and what can be done about it? This happens only when running against the production servers. It has been run in multiple test environments with no problem.

**Update 2016/04/08**

The performance is reasonable if the table-valued parameter is passed as *IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>* instead of *DataTable*. It takes 7 seconds to pass 50,000 records to using *SqlDataRecord*, but 400 seconds using *DataTable*. The problem is server-dependent. The same volume of data is passed to another server using *DataTable* with no problem.

Comment: Using a table-valued parameter to handle 200K records will definitely cause performance issues. Its performance decreases rapidly as the rows increase.  Also, transferring the data over two servers comes with performance bottlenecks due to various issues. How frequently is this stored proc run? Do these 200k records change frequently? Can you elaborate a bit more on how these 200k records are used by the stored proc?

Comment: @Amit: It performs perfectly well in the test environment, running in a few seconds. The business need is to join data across these two servers, and they cannot be linked directly.

Comment: It would perform better in test as both the db's are on same server as you mentioned. If the source table is not updated frequently then you can build some sort of ETL process to import the table from database A to B. You can also use database replication to replicate the table. You can also use `OPENQUERY` or you can do this in `.net` using `SqlBulkInsert`. I don't think the table-valued parameter approach will suit with this large dataset.

Comment: @kevincline, make sure the DataTable has the maximum length specified for string columns (otherwise defaulting to -1, which is 2GB).  Otherwise, a server side trace on the server can cause slowness with TVPs and excessive memory usage.

Comment: Are the test & production databases the same size?  It could be that either the query plan is wrong or there's so much [unindexed] data in production it can't work properly.  The other thing is that a bulk insert might be a better solution for this number of rows

Comment: @Amit: thanks, I retested using the production A with test B (different servers). That performed well. The problem occurs only with production B.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks, all string columns are VARCHAR(n) where n <= 500.

Comment: @LoztinSpace: We have a backup of B that is the same size as production. I ran against the backup B and performance was as expected (completed in a few seconds)

Comment: Reduced number of rows passed. The time increases super-linearly: 10K = 13s 20K = 31s 50K = 400s

Comment: Sounds like a bad query plan.  I know you said B is a backup but there may be other factors.  Have you tried rebuilding statistics on all the relevant tables?

Comment: @kevincline, note that I was referring the DataTable object column size property, not the SQL Server table.

Comment: @Dan, thanks. The DataTable is returned from ExecuteDataSet on A, so they are sized as they were retrieved. The VARCHAR columns are all under 50 characters.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this issue as well.  The updated finding from Kevin Cline helped us figure out why it would run fast on one server and incredibly slow on another:

> The performance is reasonable if the table-valued parameter is passed
>   as IEnumerable instead of DataTable. It takes 7 seconds
>   to pass 50,000 records to using SqlDataRecord, but 400 seconds using
>   DataTable. The problem is server-dependent. The same volume of data is
>   passed to another server using DataTable with no problem.

We discovered that having the SQL Server setting `ForceEncryption` was the difference between a fast-performing server and a slow-performing server.  If `ForceEncryption` is set to `Yes` then it performs poorly; if it is set to `No` then it performs well.  This setting is found in SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Right click Protocols -> SelectProperties -> Certificate tab -> pick your certificate -> flags tab.

So to work around this issue, you have two options.  Either turn off `ForceEncryption` setting on your database (may not be advisable), or avoid using DataTables and go for the SqlDataRecords instead as Kevin Cline suggested.